# save changes in a pandas column in python after text cleaning

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to Python. I have opened my CSV file using pandas. Here, I have applied text cleaning approaches to one of the columns (after copying the raw column "message").

**My problem is**,

When I convert my dataframe back into CSV the new column does not include the changes that I've applied such as removal of special characters. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

This is the code that I've run:

[image]

Then I have converted into csv by adding:
df.to_csv(r'Path\filename.csv)

SORTEDDDD :DDD

Comment: Are you asking how to assign the result to a new dataframe column (`df['newcol'] = ...`)), or write it out `to_csv()`? Can you please edit your question to be clearer?

Comment: Thank you about your enquiry Matthew. To clarify - I am asking how to assign the result to a csv file. Now that you've mentioned a new dataframe column I may have done this wrong. So basically in order to make changes in a column of interest I have to create a new column (i.e. copy the 'message' column) , apply code on this column and then export it as a csv?

Comment: *"assign the result to a csv file"* is mixing two things - either you assign the result to a new column in a dataframe, or you write the dataframe out (export) to CSV, or in your case, you want both. (PS I'm not Matthew)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.to_csv()` DataFrame method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your prompt response. Although, it worked to convert it into CSV format the output is not the same as represented in the console. In other words, I have applied remove punctuations on my code, and I could see it once I run it on Python but after I have applied your suggestions I cannot see the changes.